# Prolog- Put the result of a query in a list

Tags: prolog

I have these facts 
enroll(hazem,maths).
enroll(hazem,science). and so on
and I want to have 
student(X,ListOfCourses). that returns the courses X is taking in a list.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

take a look at findall/3  bagof/3, setof/3, for example :

```
student(X, ListOfCourses) :-
    findall(Courses, enroll(X, Courses), ListOfCourses).
```